# Why does Flutter PageView resets to page 0 after setState

Tags: flutter, dart, setstate, flutter-pageview

Above the first Page that shows, I show a message that the user can swipe left to go to the next page. In onPageChanged I set a bool to dismiss the message and call setState. When I swipe to page 1, at the moment setState is called, the page resets to page 0.

When I remove the conditional text, the page swipes normally.

DartPad gist: https://dartpad.dev/?id=e30a98e4bc531d9cdc93780b6e47f972

Is this a bug or do I miss something?

Full example code below:

```
import 'package:flutter/gestures.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(PageViewTestScreen());
}

class PageViewTestScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  PageViewTestScreen({super.key});

  @override
  State<PageViewTestScreen> createState() => _PageViewTestScreenState();
}

class _PageViewTestScreenState extends State<PageViewTestScreen> {
  PageController pageController = PageController(initialPage: 0);
  bool lastPage = false;
  bool userHasSlided = false;
  int numberOfPages = 5;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
  }

  void onPageChanged(int index) {
    userHasSlided = true;

    lastPage = index == levensgebieden.length-1;
    setState(() {});
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        floatingActionButton: lastPage
            ? FloatingActionButton(
                onPressed: () {},
                child: Icon(Icons.check),
              )
            : null,
        appBar: AppBar(
          foregroundColor: Colors.white,
          title: const Text("PageView bug?"),
        ),
        body: ListView(
          children: [
            const Text("Here are some pages"),
            const SizedBox(height: 6),
            if (!userHasSlided) const Text("Swipe left to continue."),
            SizedBox(
              height: 500,
              child: PageView(
                scrollBehavior: const ScrollBehavior().copyWith(dragDevices: {
                  PointerDeviceKind.touch,
                  PointerDeviceKind.mouse,
                  PointerDeviceKind.stylus,
                }),
                controller: pageController,
                onPageChanged: (int index) {
                  onPageChanged(index);
                },
                children: [
                  for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) card(i),
                ],
              ),
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget card(int index) {
    return Card(
      child: SizedBox(
          height: 500, width: 200, child: Center(child: Text("Page: $index"))),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For cases like this, providing `key` helps the element tree .

```dart
SizedBox(
  key: const Key("my_pageView"),
  height: 500,
  child: PageView(
```

More about [Keys.](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/foundation/Key-class.html)

Comment: Thanks, this is the solution indeed. I remember watching this Keys video and not understanding a tiny bit, now I re watched it again (after a year of flutter development) and still don't understand it. But I get it's signalling the flutter framework that I want to preserver state.

Answer (score 1):

This is expected, because the moment `userHasSlided` changed, the children of that `ListView` changed too, and this triggers a widget rebuild. Since the `PageView` is not a constant, it's being rebuilt as well. The rebuild interrupts the sliding progress that the user has made and therefore resetting the page to 0.

You can try adding the conditional case elsewhere (outside the `ListView`), perhaps in the `AppBar`, and remove the conditional text in the `ListView`, and you'll notice that the `PageView` will work as expected. It is because the `PageView` is not being rebuilt.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. I was confused because I did not run in such an error before, but that all children of listview are built again makes sense. Could not figure out how to start with page 1 on rebuild.